# how to update nested dictionary value with [String: Any] in swift5

Tags: swift, swift5

I have one nested dictionary that I want to update value but I have the error `error: value of type 'Any' has no subscripts`. even I force-unwrap. how can i do it?

my code

```
var users: [String: Any] = [
    "first": "abc",
    "second": ["first": "John", "last": "Williams"],
    "third": ["first": ["first": "first_first"], "last": "Williams"]
]

print(users["third"]!["first"]!["first"].updateValue("third_value", "first"))

//expected result
// var users: [String: Any] = [
//     "first": "abc",
//     "second": ["first": "John", "last": "Williams"],
//     "third": ["first": ["first": "third_value"], "last": "Williams"]
// ]
```

Comment: You need to cast each result, `(users["third"] as! [String:Any])` and so on... Whatever you are trying to do this is probably not the way forward.

Comment: Get rid of the dictionary and create a custom model

Comment: @loremipsum you mean like struct? what is good way for me to modify the value in multiple layers?

Comment: Yes, a struct. You would modify it like any other value. You are just dealing with variables at that point.

Comment: @loremipsum so since my input is json string. i need to change to decodable data struct then modify data, `Users["third.first.first"] = "third_value"`? then convert to encodable data again because my request only take encoable data? also i need to create multiple struct because I have different structure for payload? or any other better way?

Comment: Decoding and encoding a JSON string is standard procedure, it maybe 10ish lines of code. You need however many structures are required for the different objects. Look at www.QuickType.io